# IActionResult vs IResult ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

What is the difference between `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IResult` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult`? Which one should I use when I'm going to build an API? I usually use the `Results` class with its methods for that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## IActionResult vs IResult

### IActionResult

`IActionResult` is part of the MVC framework. It is found in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` namespace in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions.dll` library. Commonly it is used in MVC-based web API implementations. This has existed for quite some time, since around when ASP.NET MVC was first started. It exists in the .NET Framework, and all versions of .NET Core / .NET.

[Microsoft Learn: IActionResult Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.iactionresult)

### IResult

`IResult` is part of the new API framework introduced as part of .NET 6.0. It is found in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` namespace in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll` library. `IResult` is fully supported with the new minimal APIs features of .NET 6.0+.

[Microsoft Learn: IResult Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iresult)

Consider to use in-build dervived classes  [TypedResults or Results] instead of just IResult interface [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/responses#typedresults-vs-results).

## Do they inherit from each other?

No, these interfaces are completely separate, coming from separate namespaces and libraries.

## When should I use one vs the other?

This depends, but generally, if you are working with an MVC-based API controller, you should consider using `IActionResult` (or the base `ActionResult` class, if desired).

If you are writing APIs without MVC using .NET 6.0+, either using the Minimal API framework or something else, you should consider using `IResult`.

## Additional Microsoft Learn Resources

Here are some excellent resources from Microsoft Learn that provide overviews and helpful insights into each of these areas of API development.

[Microsoft Learn: Controller action return types in ASP.NET Core web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types)

[Microsoft Learn: ASP.NET Core Fundamentals Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/)

[Microsoft Learn: Tutorial: Create a minimal API with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/min-web-api)

[Microsoft Learn: Tutorial: Create a web API with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api)

[Microsoft Learn: Overview of ASP.NET Core MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/overview)

Answer (score 2):

IActionResult defines sort of contract, as it is an interface, which allows you to provide some more operations based on your actions like redirecting, changing the response's format etc.. Actions are like new layer in the code between http dialogues and your MVC web application to provide more operations depends on http requests so you will be able to reach any of endpoints in your API by any type of request that correspond with Http protocol. I highly recommend you to use IActionResult on the side of your web application - MVC, since it gives you more approaches to handle requests.
Hope it helped you :)